# Back Up window with password

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I use Ubuntu 12.4. Recently I have been getting a back up icon appear on the left hand bar. When I open it I am prompted to supply a password. I enter my password and it appears that the system is backing up, then only to have the same window appear as before again asking for a password. I am not sure if the back up has taken place or not. Also I have tried ticking the box 'remember my password' and this makes no difference.

Is this working correctly. If not what can I do to fix it.

Comment: The backups (Déjà Dup) password is user defined in the initial setup. It may or may not be the same as your user's. Try remembering what password you used during the initial setup.